# maven: define and use different scenarios for building

Tags: maven

Is it possible *without making a new plugin* to define different "scenarios" in a maven `pom.xml`?

More specifically I want to have  `mvn clean install` do its job further, but I'd like the same `pom` file to alternatively make a standalone jar (perhaps with a different set of `plugins`). for example by using `mvn clean make-my-jar`.

Comment: Add your plugin to your pom file and you can separate via `mvn clean verify` running unit- and integration tests and via `mvn clean deploy` you can run on top packaging via maven-shade/maven-assembly-plugin ? Default Java project or using particular framework like quarkus/spring boot? In the majority of the cases you don't need `mvn clean install`...

Comment: What different "scenarios" do you want to cover with the same POM?